# Webcam not working in ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, webcam

I have installed ubuntu 13.04 but my webcam is not working.My laptop is Dell Inspiron 3521,it came with ubuntu installed and last time I remember webcam was working but now when I installed its not working.
How can I fix this issue?
Do I need some drivers for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to download a program called "Cheese" from the software center. It's basically the Ubuntu equivalent of Photo Booth on a Mac.

Comment: I downloaded but still its not detecting webcam I am only getting black screen

Comment: Is there a light going on next to the webcam to display that it's on?

Comment: No there is no such light,anyway I have found its camera's fault not of software. @danr5509

Answer (score 0):

Cheeze works quite well, but its' performance is poor, and the quality is poor (especially if you have a basic webcam).

A better choice is "GTK UVC video viewer". This program is more than a camera tool, can take movies and snapshots, save them for later use, etc. Its' picture quality is somewhat better too, noticable on my Compaq laptop, with a VGA webcam. It was ideal for making a snapshot of myself for my user account photo .